# Data scraping from multiple links

Tags: php, html, xpath, web-scraping, domdocument

I have a PHP code that will retrieve data from the class name of "level0 nav-1 active parent". Is there a way where I can provide an array of links and use a slightly different class name for each looping array of links without having to repeat the same code for like 10 links?

Something like:
First link(https://www.postme.com.my/men-1.html) - use class ("level0 nav-1 active parent")
Second(https://www.postme.com.my/women.html) - use class ("level0 nav-2 active parent")
Third(https://www.postme.com.my/children.html) - use class ("level0 nav-3 active parent")

Notice the incrementing nav-#?

This is the php code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$grep = new DoMDocument();
@$grep->loadHTMLFile("https://www.postme.com.my/men-1.html");

$finder = new DomXPath($grep);
$classCat = "level0 nav-1 active parent";

$nodesCat = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classCat')]");

$i = 0;

    foreach ($nodesCat as $node) {
    $span = $node->childNodes;
    $replace = str_replace("Items 1-12 of", "",$span->item(1)->nodeValue);

    echo $replace. " : ";
  }

  // Check another link using class name of "level0 nav-2 active parent"
  //repeat code 

  @$grep->loadHTMLFile("https://www.postme.com.my/women.html");

$finder = new DomXPath($grep);
$classCat = "level0 nav-2 active parent";

$nodesCat = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classCat')]");

$i = 0;

    foreach ($nodesCat as $node) {
    $span = $node->childNodes;
    $replace = $span->item(1)->nodeValue;

    echo $replace. " : ";
  }
//check another link with class name "level0 nav-3 active parent".
//notice the incrementing nav-#?
//I don't want to make the code long just because each link is using a slightly different class name to refer to the data.
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: what particular data are you trying to get here anyway? do you need to get the links (dropdown) value text?

Comment: the categories in the menu bar(MEN,WOMEN,KIDS,..)

Comment: just to clarify? do you want to get the categories from `men` to `others`?

Comment: yeah but im not sure if its possible since the class name used are slightly different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is get the parent of those links (`<li>`) which is the `<ul id="nav">`. Then from there. extract the values. Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://www.postme.com.my/men-1.html');
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$categories = $xpath->query('//ul[@id="nav"]/li');

foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo $xpath->query('./a/span', $category)->item(0)->nodeValue . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! One more thing...is there a way to not output the word "Array" and the numbers [0],etc? Or is it come together when you output ($data)?

Comment: @Cael i just pushed it inside an array that's why, i made a revision, try it